# Reconocer valores y acumularlos

Tags: python

Espero que esten bien, necesito que mi funcion reconozca la letra, y dependiendo de cual sume puntos a una variable llamada de igual forma, pero a la hora de correr el programa me pone que la variable puntos toma el valor de 0, o si cambio la parte de los "if / else" termina tomando valores de 40 en adelante. Claramente hay un error en la parte de los If, pero no lo estaria encontrando, les dejo igualmente lo que hize, para ver si me pueden ayudar a econtrarlo, desde ya muchisimas gracias a todos!!

```py
def Puntos(candidata):
    Puntos=0
    Pvocal1=0
    Pconsonante2=0
    Pdificil5=0
    vocales=["a","e","i","o","u"]
    dificiles=["j","k","q","w","x","y","z"]
    consonate=["r","t","p","s","d","f","g","h","l","c","v","b","n","m"]
    for letra in candidata:
        if letra in vocales:
                puntos+=1
        if letra in consonate:
                puntos+=2
        if letra in dificiles:
                puntos+=5
    return Puntos

print(Puntos(**cualquier palabra**)


Edit: no me exprese bien sobre lo que queria lograr con el codigo Ñ depende del tipo de letra que la palabra que yo ingreso tenga (vocal, consonante, o una "dificil") que sume puntos a un acumulador. Por ejemplo: yo ingreso la palabra "hola", y la funcion me tiene que devolver 6. Mi codigo no me devuelve nada, me da 0 siempre.
```

Comment: cuidado con las mayúsculas/minúsculas. tu variable contador es `puntos`, pero retornas `Puntos` (el cual por otro lado coincide con el nombre de la función, con lo que tampoco es buena idea)

Comment: otro detalle es que `vocales` y las otras listas podrían ser directamente cadenas, es decir,  `vocales ="aeiou"` y funcionaría igual porque el operador `in` también sirve para buscar en cadenas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un problema es la confusión entre el nombre de la función y la variable. Ahora solo se diferencian en la mayúscula.  Para tener menos confusiones, y para ayudar a entender el código, se aconseja de emplear nombres más concretos para cada cosa. Por ejemplo `calcula_puntos` como nombre de la función. Las listas de letras se podrían simplificar cambiándolas por una cadena de letras.

Otra cosa que puede ayudar en comprender mejor el código es emplear `elif` para aclarar que cada opción es exclusive.

```
def calcula_puntos(candidata):
    puntos = 0
    vocales = 'aeiou'
    dificiles = 'jkqwxyz'
    consonantes = 'rtpsdfghlcvbnm'
    for letra in candidata:
        if letra in vocales:
            puntos += 1
        elif letra in consonantes:
            puntos += 2
        elif letra in dificiles:
            puntos += 5
    return puntos

print(calcula_puntos("cualquier palabra"))
```

También se podría emplear ['una lista por comprensión'](https://entrenamiento-python-basico.readthedocs.io/es/latest/leccion10/listas_comprension.html) para comprimir el código. Al principio puede parecer un poco raro, pero para código más complejo puede ser una manera potente para obtener código más fácil a cambiar.

Aunque en este ejemplo no ayuda mucho, lo dejo aquí por si acaso:

```
def calcula_puntos_v2(candidata):
    vocales = 'aeiou'
    dificiles = 'jkqwxyz'
    consonantes = 'rtpsdfghlcvbnm'
    return sum([1 if letra in vocales else 2 if letra in consonantes else 5 if letra in dificiles else 0
                for letra in candidata])

print(calcula_puntos_v2("cualquier palabra"))
```

PD: Aquí el código original con los cambios mínimos para que funciona. El problema principal es la confusión entre 'puntos' como variable y 'Puntos' como nombre de la función.

```py
def Puntos(candidata):
    puntos=0  # <---- la variable empieza con minuscula
    # Pvocal1=0 # <---- estas tres variables no estan utilizados
    # Pconsonante2=0
    # Pdificil5=0
    vocales=["a","e","i","o","u"]
    dificiles=["j","k","q","w","x","y","z"]
    consonate=["r","t","p","s","d","f","g","h","l","c","v","b","n","m"]
    for letra in candidata:
        if letra in vocales:
                puntos+=1
        if letra in consonate:
                puntos+=2
        if letra in dificiles:
                puntos+=5
    return puntos   # <---- hay que retornar el variable 'puntos' con minuscula

print(Puntos("hola"))
```

Esto si imprime `6`.

Comment: Hola! Muchisimas gracias por ayudarme a clarificar mi codigo, releyendo lo que yo pregunte, no me exprese bien sobre lo que queria lograr con el codigo Ñ depende del tipo de letra que la palabra que yo ingreso tenga (vocal, consonante, o una "dificil") que sume puntos a un acumulador. Por ejemplo: yo ingreso la palabra "hola", y la funcion me tiene que devolver 6. Mi codigo no me devuelve nada, me da 0 siempre.  Desde ya te re agradezco el timempo que te tomas en ayudar!!

Comment: Ay, no sabes lo que te amo JAJJA, posta re mil millones de gracias por ayudarme, estuve frustrada desde ayer pensando como resolver esto, asi que nada, mil gracias